# How to save web page in sd card?

Tags: android, webview

I want to save webview content in sd card.
I tried to save like `capturePicture` and save it in sd, but for some big websites, it just kill my app, because heap is too high.
I was hear about, saving website like .pdf file, but I can't find any good suggestion.

Acctually, I want to make it like in pc it happends. 
For example, firefox create .htm file and folder with images.
How I can easy do it, and then get .htm file with images in webview?

Comment: I don't need Capture current, beacause this method is useless, if I want to save some big websites! I need some method, which not makes it work so hard, for device.

Comment: Saw this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911666/storing-a-webview-for-offline-browsing-android